# ggplot2 to plot mean and sd of a variable side by side

Tags: r, ggplot2, combinedchart

I am trying to create a plot of the mean and sd (side by side) of a variable for two different groups in R to get something like this.

[image]

where blue bars are means and orange bars are SDs.

I use the ggplot2 package in R for this. 
If I use these codes separately

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(grouping variable), y=my variable)) + stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar", col="blue")

ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(grouping variable), y=my variable)) + stat_summary(fun.y="sd", geom="bar", col="orange")
```

they function well but produce the mean and sd in two different graphs.

So I tried to combine them in one graph by using

```
stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean" and stat = "summary", fun.y = "sd"
```

and what I got

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(grouping variable)) + geom_bar(aes(y=my variable), stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", position="dodge",col="blue") + geom_bar(aes(y=my variable), stat = "summary", fun.y = "sd", position="dodge",col="orange")
```

and the following error has emerged

> Error: unexpected symbol in:
>   "ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(grouping variable)) + geom_bar(aes(y=my variable), stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", position="dodge",col="blue") + geom_bar(aes(y=my variable), stat = "summary", fun.y = "sd", positi
>   ggplot"

Could you help to fix the error or maybe there is another way to do this?

**Updated information:**
the sample of my data looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgJTv.png)

I run the following code on these data to plot mean tTTO and sd tTTO for both interviewers:

```
ggplot(timeTTO, aes(x=interviewer, y=tTTO)) + 
  theme_light() + 
  labs(title = "Figure 3. Time taken to complete a single TTO task, by interviewer", x=NULL, y=NULL) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold")) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean",width=0.25, fill = "blue") + 
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun.y = "sd", width=0.25,fill = "orange")
```

and I got something like this where blue bars are the means and orange bars are SDs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRBKo.png)

Actually, I have tried with position="dodge" put it in both geom_bar() functions, it did not work

Comment: Actually, it was fixed with this code ggplot(data, aes(x=grouping variable, y=my variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean",width=0.25, fill = "blue", col="blue") + geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun.y = "sd", width=0.25,fill = "orange", col="orange")        BUT still need help to plot them side by side for now they are overlapping each other. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `position="dodge"` is for geom's of the same x, but not for stat's. I came up with two solutions.

In the first, I kept your stat_summary's and used `position_nudge` to manually put the bars in your specified positions. Notice how the legend doesn't work either because there is no actual plot data, just stat layers.

In the second, I did the data analysis before ggplot, using group_by, summarize, and then gather to make the data long. Then we can use the regular `geom_col` now that the data has already been processed.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tibble(interviewer = c("i2", "i1", "i1", "i2", "i1"), tTTO = c(245, 251, 99, 85, 101)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=interviewer, y=tTTO)) + 
  theme_light() + 
  labs(title = "Figure 3. Time taken to complete a single TTO task, by interviewer", x=NULL, y=NULL) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"), legend.position = "bottom") + 
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", position = position_nudge(x = -0.125, y = 0), width = 0.25, fill = "blue") + 
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun.y = "sd", position = position_nudge(x = 0.125, y = 0), width = 0.25, fill = "orange")
```

[image]

```r
  # Notice that the legend does not work for stat geoms

tibble(interviewer = c("i2", "i1", "i1", "i2", "i1"), tTTO = c(245, 251, 99, 85, 101)) %>%
  group_by(interviewer) %>%
  summarize(mean(tTTO), sd(tTTO)) %>%
  gather(key = "type", value = "value", 2:3) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=interviewer, y=value, fill=type)) + 
  theme_light() + 
  labs(title = "Figure 3. Time taken to complete a single TTO task, by interviewer", x=NULL, y=NULL) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"), legend.position = "bottom") + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge", width = 0.25) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue","orange"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Dear Arthur, I added the sample of my data and the code which works, and actually, I have tried position="dodge", it did not work, the bars are still overlapping. Thanks!